# Get full path as reference name

Tags: cross-referencing

I would like to have the full path of a reference, when I reference a label.

Basic example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section Alpha}
\subsection{Subsection 1}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*)\,}]
    \item Item a
    
    \item Item b
    
    \begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*.}]
        \item \label{subitemOne} Sub-Item 1
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

Reference example (ref: \ref{subitemOne})

\end{document}
```

I am looking for something that would make my last line look like this:
`Reference example (ref: 1-1-1b-1)`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: it always helps to provide a complete small test document rather than a fragment, avoids typos and for example you are using a non standard `enumerate` syntax (I could guess which package you are using but I shouldn't have to guess)

Comment: Will enumerated lists always occur within `\subsection` levels? Or could they occur at the `\section` level, let alone at the `\chapter` level, as well? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico `\section` is possible `\chapter` isn't possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that employs the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to (a) create a two-level custom enumerate-like environment (called `myenum` -- feel free to choose a different name) and (b) use the package's `ref` option to set the desired cross-referencing format for the corresponding level-1 and level-2 enumerated items.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{2} % create 2-level enumerate-like env.
\setlist[myenum,1]{label=\alph*), ref=\thesubsection-\alph*}
\setlist[myenum,2]{label={\arabic*.}, ref=\themyenumi-\arabic*}

\begin{document}
\refstepcounter{chapter}

\section{Section Alpha}
\subsection{Subsection Uno}

\begin{myenum}
    \item Item a \label{itemOne} 
    \item Item b   
    \begin{myenum}
        \item  Sub-Item 1 \label{subitemOne}
    \end{myenum}
\end{myenum}

\section{Section Beta}
\subsection{Subsection Due}

\begin{myenum}
    \item Item ax \label{itemOnex}  
    \item Item bx    
    \begin{myenum}
        \item  Sub-Item 1x 
        \item  Sub-Item 2x \label{subitemTwox}
    \end{myenum}
\end{myenum}
\noindent
Cross-referenced enumerated items: 
\ref{itemOne}\ \ref{subitemOne}\ \ref{itemOnex}\ \ref{subitemTwox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

[image]

You seem to be using `enumitem` which has a `ref` key to control this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section Alpha}
\subsection{Subsection 1}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*)\,}]
    \item Item a
    
    \item Item b
    
    \begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*.},ref=\thesubsection-\alph{enumi}-\arabic*]
        \item \label{subitemOne} Sub-Item 1
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

Reference example (ref: \ref{subitemOne})
\end{document}
```

Comment: wow, thanks! that works! is it possible to have this autmatically added to all enumerates? I guess it will be a bit tricky, as they can be nested, as in this example...

Comment: @misanthrop you can set up different conventions for differently nested enumerate, see mico's answer, slightly trickier is detectig if you are in a section or subsection etc (you'd neeed to check for 0 values in the relevant counters. Note both answers posted are entirely based on the `enumitem` package, that you didn't mention in the question:-)